# Controller has no segue with identifier

Tags: ios, uitableview, didselectrowatindexpath

I connected my UITableViewController to a NavigationController with ctrl, defined the segue as "modal" and defined the segue identifier "DetailEvent".

In the class of my UITableViewController I added this code:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{    
    NSLog(@"Row Selected = %i",indexPath.row);
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"DetailEvent" sender:self.view];
}
```

Error:

```
Row Selected = 1
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Receiver (<AvailableEventsController: 0xa335500>) has no segue with identifier 'DetailEvent''
*** First throw call stack:
(0x175b012 0x1580e7e 0x5aa492 0xa6b53fa 0x103a0 0x5778d5 0x577b3d 0xf7ee83 0x171a376 0x1719e06 0x1701a82 0x1700f44 0x1700e1b 0x23ee7e3 0x23ee668 0x4c865c 0xbf7d 0x2755)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Have you mentioned identifier in storyboard?

Comment: Identifier is set to "DetailEvent" in the storyboard.

Comment: [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"DetailEvent" sender:nil];

Comment: Doesn't change the fact that it doesn't find the Segue.

Comment: Make sure that the class of the source controller is set to `AvailableEventsController`.  Make sure that the start of the segue is the controller itself rather than a table view or a cell.  If you don't see anything obvious in that, you can select the storyboard and open as source code.  Search for `<segue ` and you may be able to get better information from the XML description of the one with that identifier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was working on a different UIViewController in the StoryBoard.